# Traits or overriding for behaviour

Tags: design-patterns, overriding, traits

i'm having a dilemma which one is better in the following case:

```
Movie
|
ActionMovie HorrorMovie ChristmasMovie ...
|                   |               |
AdultActionMovie AdultHorrorMovie AdultChristmasMovie
```

in Movie there is a watch function, for the adult movies you need to check 18+
So i have:

```
void watch(viewer) {
if(check(viewer)) {
.. enjoy movie
}
else
.. you don't fit requirements
}
```

the check in  ActionMovie HorrorMovie ChristmasMovie ...

```
bool check(viewer) {
return true; // nothing to check
}
```

the check in AdultActionMovie AdultHorrorMovie AdultChristmasMovie

```
bool check(viewer) {
return viewer.age >= 18; // check age
}
```

**Now the real question is**: should i just **override** check in the adult classes (and possible other subclasses), **or** should i **use two traits**, one which provides the normal check method (return true) which is used by ActionMovie etc, and another one (age >; 18) which is used by the adult classes?

Please provide a reason why you should pick one above the other because in my opinion these are quite  the same?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I know your question is about traits/method overriding, but I believe the scenario you're dealing with is related to the way inheritance is used to model the solution.

Notice that, to express a movie is for adults, a new class has to be created for each kind of movie, and that also gets reflected as duplication in `watch` methods.

Also, if a new kind of movie needs to be added, say `ComedyMovie`, you'll also need to create `AdultComedyMovie`. If you also need to handle child movies, you'll end up with `AdultComedyMovie`, `ChildComediMovie`, and so on.

**Analysis**
It seems that you're missing movie ratings and genre in your model. That's why the *explosion* of genre/rating shows off in the bottom of the hierarchy.

Notice that, if you have adult and children, number of classes needed in your solution equals 1 (`Movie`) + N (# genres) + 2N (an extra class for each rating).

You could model `Rating` to implement many as you want (adult, children, etc.) without having to change the way movies are modeled.

You didn't say nothing about genre, so I'll assume that a symbol/string is enough to represent them.

That way, you'll only need one class to represent movies, `Movie`, and one class to represent ratings, `AdultRating`.

**Model**

Here's a quick description of classes that you might use to solve your design problem.
To keep things simple, I decided to separate check and validation when someone asks to watch a movie.

`Movie`
Models a movie in your problem domain. Knows which genre it belongs to and it's rating.

`Rating`
Encapsulates restrictions that should be met by a person in order to watch a movie. Different ratings will have different implementations (adult, children).

`Ticket Controller`
You can think of it as the employee at the entrance of the auditorium asking for tickets, and deciding whether or not you're allowed to watch the movie.

Warning: `TicketController` *is a **bad** name. "Controller" is overused enough and could mean a lot of different things, so please find a better name for it :)*

**Vanilla Implemention**

```
class TicketController

  public void isAllowedToWatch(aViewer, aMovie) {
    if !aMovie.isRecommendedFor(aViewer) {
      throw new Exception("You're not allowed to watch this movie");
    }
  }

}

class Movie

  public void new(aRating, aGenre) {
    rating = aRating;
    genre = aGenre; // unused
  }

  public bool isRecommendedFor(aViewer) {
    return rating.isSatisfiedBy(aViewer);
  }
}

public class AdultRating

  public bool isSatisfiedBy(aViewer) {
    return aViewer.isOlderThan(18);
  }
}
```

**Usage**

Assuming you have instances of Movie, TicketController and a viewer:

```
void watch(aViewer, aMovie) {
  ticketController.isAllowedToWatch(aViewer, aMovie);
  // proceed with the original stuff :)
  ... enjoy movie
}
```